# 404 not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo un proyecto en codeigniter, el cual funciona a la perfección en Windows ahora al pasar dicho proyecto a ubuntu con apache me tira error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /aressoftwarecontrol/Login/validarIngreso was not
>   found on this server.

El mismo se presente luego de intentar hacer login.

El Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        IndexIgnore */*
        RewriteEngine on

        # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

El resto de archivos tanto config, routes, index los tengo por defecto no se ha modificado nada.

La versión de codeigniter es **3.1.10**

Quiza alguna sugerencia gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy seguro que tu error se debe a dos cosas:

1. El .htaccess no lo lee bien `ubuntu` y tienes que cambiarlo. Tienes que cambiar tanto el `.htaccess` que está en la raíz, como el que está dentro de la carpeta `application`

Te muestro:

.htaccess (el de la raíz)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

Y el .htaccess que está dentro de la carpeta `application` quedaría así:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Cabe mencionar que si tienes otro tipo de configuración ya añadida a estos archivos, los conserves y solo los adiciones.

Ahora bien, con respecto a este error más en específico:

> Not Found The requested URL /aressoftwarecontrol/Login/validarIngreso
>   was not found on this server.

2. El servidor está respondiendo por la cuestión del `.htaccess` mal configurado que no lo encuentra. Entonces, tu controlador debe de llamarse tanto dentro del script como en el nombre del archivo `Login.php`, el controlador debería de quedar como al final de la respuesta:

Algunos servidores son sensibles para mayúsculas y minúsculas y presiento que también tu servidor es sensible ante esto, por lo que es necesario también que tu controlador se llame igual como te menciono al final de la respuesta.

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function validarIngreso() {
    //...
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero editando el htaccess tanto raiz como el de application aun persiste el error , los nombres los tengo bien tal como mencionas, pero es extraño que no funcione..

Comment: ¿Podrías darme un ejemplo de la url que visitas y hace que te dé el error que mencionas?

Comment: Gracias funciono tu configuracion comente el htaccess anterior y coloque el tuyo funciono bien..gracias..!!

Comment: Por nada, qué bueno que te fue de ayuda. Saludos.